# The purpose of particular anonymous function

Tags: javascript, browser, anonymous-function

I have difficulty understanding what the following function is going to do. I need to understand what is the purpose of this function since I got different reaction using different browsers while running this function.

```
function anonymous() 
{ 
    return(function()
           {
               'use strict';
                return !this&&!!Function.prototype.bind;
           }
    ());
}
```

Comment: Kind of an ignorant return honestly. You can literally take away the IIFE and just use whats inside of the IIFE. Also the first function is not an anonymous function an anonymous function is `var a = function(){ };` as you see there is no name after function which makes it an anonymous function. This is a named function called `anonymous`

Comment: It would help if  you described what that different reaction you get from different browsers is and what you expect the code to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually not a that bad question, the `'use strict';` indicates that the code inside the function should be evaluated in strict mode which is part of ECMAScript5.

With strict mode enabled, you can not use undeclared variables - which is important here. If your browser is capable of ECMAScript5 the `this` variable is undeclared i.e `undefined`. If your browser does not support ECMAScript5 `this` is usually the `Window`.

So this is a compatibility check whether your browser supports ECMAScript5 or not:

```
'use strict';
var hasECMAScript5 = !this;
```

Then, the expression `!!Function.prototype.bind` checks whether your browser has support for bound functions (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

Answer (score 2):

It tests if a browser supports both [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) and [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

It uses an IIFE because the value of `this` depends on how a function is called. By using a new function, you guarantee what the context it is called in will be.